# Issue in generating bubblechart using the D3 in Angular2

Tags: d3.js, angular

I tried creating a bubblechart using the D3 in Angular2 component. But I am facing some issues in generating it. Not sure what is the mistake. Please find the       plunkr URL **https://plnkr.co/edit/eTi58RL5gipHUseAT9GA** for the code.
can any one help me on this?

Code to generate chart in D3 with angular2

```
import {Component, View, Directive, Input, Output, Inject, Injectable, provide} from 'angular2/core'; 
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';

import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES, NgClass, Control, ControlGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';

import {RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router, LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';

import {Http, HTTP_PROVIDERS, RequestOptions, Headers, Request, RequestMethod} from 'angular2/http'

//Declaratives for d3  and linq
declare var d3: any;
declare var Enumerable: any;
declare var c3: any;


@Component({
    selector: 'bubble-chart',
    template: 
    `<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node:hover {
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node--leaf {
  fill: white;
}

.label {
  font: 11px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-anchor: middle;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff, 1px 0 0 #fff, -1px 0 0 #fff, 0 -1px 0 #fff;
}

.label,
.node--root,
.node--leaf {
  pointer-events: none;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`
})

export class BubbleChartComponent {

    constructor()
    {

    }
    margin = 20;
    diameter = 960;

    color = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([-1, 5])
        .range(["hsl(152,80%,80%)", "hsl(228,30%,40%)"])
        .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

    pack = d3.layout.pack()
        .padding(2)
        .size([this.diameter - this.margin, this.diameter - this.margin])
        .value(function (d) { return d.size; })

    svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", this.diameter)
        .attr("height", this.diameter)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.diameter / 2 + "," + this.diameter / 2 + ")");

    chart = d3.json("flare.json", function (error, root) {
        if (error) throw error;

        var focus = root,
            nodes = this.pack.nodes(root),
            view;

        var circle = this.svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", function (d) { return d.parent ? d.children ? "node" : "node node--leaf" : "node node--root"; })
            .style("fill", function (d) { return d.children ? this.color(d.depth) : null; })
            .on("click", function (d) { if (focus !== d) zoom(d), d3.event.stopPropagation(); });

        var text = this.svg.selectAll("text")
            .data(nodes)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .style("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.parent === root ? 1 : 0; })
            .style("display", function (d) { return d.parent === root ? "inline" : "none"; })
            .text(function (d) { return d.name; });

        var node = this.svg.selectAll("circle,text");

        d3.select("body")
            .style("background", this.color(-1))
            .on("click", function () { zoom(root); });

        zoomTo([root.x, root.y, root.r * 2 + this.margin]);

        function zoom(d) {
            var focus0 = focus; focus = d;

            var transition = d3.transition()
                .duration(d3.event.altKey ? 7500 : 750)
                .tween("zoom", function (d) {
                    var i = d3.interpolateZoom(view, [focus.x, focus.y, focus.r * 2 + this.margin]);
                    return function (t) { zoomTo(i(t)); };
                });

            transition.selectAll("text")
                .filter(function (d) { return d.parent === focus || this.style.display === "inline"; })
                .style("fill-opacity", function (d) { return d.parent === focus ? 1 : 0; })
                .each("start", function (d) { if (d.parent === focus) this.style.display = "inline"; })
                .each("end", function (d) { if (d.parent !== focus) this.style.display = "none"; });
        }

        function zoomTo(v) {
            var k = this.diameter / v[2]; view = v;
            node.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + (d.x - v[0]) * k + "," + (d.y - v[1]) * k + ")"; });
            circle.attr("r", function (d) { return d.r * k; });
        }
    });

    chart1 = d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", this.diameter + "px");
   // d3.select(this.self.frameElement).style("height", this.diameter + "px");
}
```

Comment: Can you please describe exactly what your 'issues' are?  And please read [this](stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you have a lot of mistakes related with current context `this`.

You can see the working plunkr at this page https://embed.plnkr.co/qM3qrk3swvalQFBh1Db1/